# Error when loading an image from the assets

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use a PNG file as an icon image.

I have an `assets` folder in the root of my project.

The file's path is `assets/icons/Dumbbell.png`.

I loaded my assets in the pubspec file:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
```

And in a Stateful widget's state I'm trying to use it:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
           BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Workout'),
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/Dumbbell.png',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I just can't make it work!

EDIT: I removed the `const` keyword and added another `BottomNavigationBarItem` and now everything is working perfectly!

Comment: I assume you're loading that image from a dart package? Otherwise, you should remove the package property.

Comment: Thank you for your observation! It was something I was trying out, but without success. I just edit my questions, but it doesn't work anyways

Comment: (In Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2 anyway), that const is going to cause an error and also there's an assertion requiring at least two children in the BottomNavigationBarItem[].  Are you getting an error of some kind, like an assertion failure?  Add another BottomNavigatorBarItem and see.

Comment: @Leandro are you receiving a runtime error? Or you just don't see the image rendered? (I'm not able right now to test your code)

Comment: Did you rerun get package for pubspec.yml after add line    - assets/icons/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your issue, just remove the `const` keyword because your icon is not constant and also you need at least two `BottomNavigationBarItem` widgets to make it work:

```
    items: [
           BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Workout'),
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/Dumbbell.png',
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Another item'),
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/Dumbbell.png',
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

More info here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Answer (score -1):

try again with this demo

```
Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/intro_0.jpg'),fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,)
```

diegoveloper's words is right. and BottomNavigationBar need two more items.
those code worked:

```
    bottomNavigationBar:BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                title: Text('Workout'),
                icon: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/intro_0.jpg'),fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                title: Text('Workout'),
                icon: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/intro_0.jpg'),fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
            ),
        ],
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer code_Li, but it didn't work :/ Any other suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

try this..

use ImageIcon class instead of Image.asset

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/mascot.png")),
              title: Text("workout"),
            ),

          ],
 ),
```